# Directory Content Count Using Linux Find Command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line

How can I populate the placeholder [COUNT] in the following Linux find command with total number of files plus folders for each sub-directory inside SomeFolder where am using bash:

```
find '/SomeFolder' -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -printf '%f **[COUNT]**\n' | sort
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `find` just to print out the directories, then pipe the output to `xargs` to produce the counts, you could write it like this:

```
find '/SomeFolder' -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -print0 |
  xargs -0 -IDIR sh -c 'echo "$(basename "DIR"): $(ls "DIR" | wc -l)"' |
  sort
```

Which gets you output like:

```
android-otp-extractor: 1
ansible: 13
argocd-app-of-app-chart: 1
asan: 0
asm: 0
aws-secrets: 0
backup: 0
```

But as @Jetchisel said, you don't really need `find` for what you're doing; this should get you the same thing:

```
ls --zero -d /SomeFolder/*/ |
  xargs -0 -IDIR sh -c 'echo "$(basename "DIR"): $(ls "DIR" | wc -l)"' |
  sort
```

(We're using `--zero` with `ls` and `-print0` with `find` in order to correctly handle directory names that contain whitespace.)

Comment: Hmm. Is `ls | wc -l` better or worse than something like `set -- "$DIR"/*` and then using `$#`? I suppose it's different pitfalls either way.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if `find` is really needed with `globstar` on with `bash` but, here it is.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

count=0

while IFS= read -rd '' sub_dirs; do
  shopt -s globstar nullglob dotglob
  count=("$sub_dirs"/**)
  shopt -u globstar nullglob dotglob
  printf '%s: %d\n' "$sub_dirs" "${#count[*]}"
done < <(find /Somedir -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -print0) |
sort -k2 -n
```